# Git: Who did last merge & push

Tags: git, github

I see that our master branch was merged accidentally to production branch.
I can see all the commits and who made them and when.

But how can I see who (username) and when moved all those commits to the production branch?

(we are using Github if it is important)

Answer (score 0):

Make a `git log COMMIT_HASH` if you say you know the merge commit. If you do not know the merge commit id make a `git reflog master`

Answer (score 0):

Git log has a option to only display merge commits. This displays the latest merge on production_branch

```
git checkout production_branch
git log --merges -n1
```

Comment: It shows me the last merge that was done to master branch few days ago

Comment: Did you check out your production branch before you used the log command? @PavelBernshtam

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
gitk
```

or

```
gitk --all
```

Works pretty well if your commit tree has relatively small amount of branches